# Django - No logro que el formulario se visualice

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Soy nuevo en Django y estoy intentando crear una aplicación sencilla para gestionar una base de datos de clientes.
No logro que el formulario se visualice en el template, sin embargo es bien renderizado (lo probé a través de manage.py shell y lo creó con todas las etiquetas HTML).

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from arqumhome.models import Cliente
from arqumhome.forms import CargarForm


def index(request):
    contenido = {'nombre_sitio': 'Arqum'}
    return render(request, 'arqumhome/index.html', contenido)


def altacliente(request):
    return render(request, 'arqumhome/altacliente.html')


def bajacliente(request):
    return render(request, 'arqumhome/bajacliente.html')


def consultacliente(request):
    return render(request, 'arqumhome/consultacliente.html')


def cargar_cliente(request):

    form = CargarForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        nombre_cliente = form.cleaned_data['nombre_cliente']
        domicilio_real = form.cleaned_data['domicilio_real']
        domicilio_obra = form.cleaned_data['domicilio_obra']
        correo = form.cleaned_data['correo']
        telefono = form.cleaned_data['telefono']
        fecha_alta_cliente = form.cleaned_data['fecha_alta_cliente']
        fecha_inicio_obra = form.cleaned_data['fecha_inicio_obra']
        fecha_fin_obra = form.cleaned_data['fecha_fin_obra']

        newcliente = Cliente(nombre_cliente=nombre_cliente, domicilio_real=domicilio_real, domicilio_obra=domicilio_obra, correo=correo,
                             telefono=telefono, fecha_alta_cliente=fecha_alta_cliente, fecha_inicio_obra=fecha_inicio_obra, fecha_fin_obra=fecha_fin_obra)
        newcliente.save()

        return redirect("index")

    return render(request, 'arqumhome/formulario.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Cliente


class CargarForm(forms.Form):
    nombre_cliente = forms.CharField(
        label='Nombre del cliente:', max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control' 'input-50'}))
    domicilio_real = forms.CharField(
        label='Domicilio real:', max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    domicilio_obra = forms.CharField(
        label='Domicilio de obra:', max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    correo = forms.EmailField(
        label='Correo electrónico:', max_length=254, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    telefono = forms.CharField(
        label='Teléfono:', max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    fecha_alta_cliente = forms.DateField(
        label='Fecha de alta de cliente:', widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(2019, 2100), attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    fecha_inicio_obra = forms.DateField(
        label='Fecha de inicio de obra:', widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(2019, 2100), attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    fecha_fin_obra = forms.DateField(
        label='Fecha de alta de cliente:', widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(2019, 2100), attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    error_messages = {
        'nombre_cliente': {
            'required': ("El nombre del cliente es obligatorio"),
        },
        'domicilio_real': {
            'required': ("El domicilio real es obligatorio"),
        },
        'domicilio_obra': {
            'required': ("El domicilio de obra es obligatorio"),
        },
        'correo': {
            'required': ("Debe proporcionar correo electrónico"),
        },
        'fecha_alta_cliente': {
            'required': ("Debe informar la fecha de alta del cliente"),
        },
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CargarForm, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from arqumhome import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('altacliente', views.altacliente, name='altacliente'),
    path('bajacliente', views.bajacliente, name='bajacliente'),
    path('consultacliente', views.consultacliente, name='consultacliente'),
    path('cargar_cliente', views.cargar_cliente, name='cargar_cliente'),
]
```

Hasta ahí los archivos del backend. Yo creo que el problema se encuentra en alguna línea del método cargar_cliente de views.py pero no logro darme cuenta de cuál es.

Ahora copio los archivos HTML:

**altacliente.html**

```
<!--CONTENEDOR DE FORMULARIO PARA ALTA DE CLIENTE-->

{% extends "arqumhome/plantilla.html" %}
{% block main %}
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    <h2 id="titAltaCliente" class="page-title">Alta de Cliente</h2>
    <br>
    <div id="contentClienteAlta">
        <div id="contentAlta">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="expContent col-sm-10">
                    <div class="control-container form-vertical">
                        <h4 class="page-title">Complete los campos</h4>
                        <hr class="page-title-divider">
                        {% block formulario %}{% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnAltaCliente" class="btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" value="Dar de alta">
                    <button type="button" id="btnVolverInicio" class="btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" onclick="location.href="{% url 'index' %}"">Volver</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

**formulario.html**

```
{% extends "arqumhome/altacliente.html" %}

{% block formulario %}
<form action="{% url 'cargar_cliente' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {{ field }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Por si es necesario aclararlo, dentro de static estoy utilizando bootstrap y jquery.

Esta es una imagen de lo que me muestra el inspector del navegador (probé en Chrome y Firefox):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]